# PYQT layout and setgeometry basic overview

Tags: python, pyqt

Im trying to get my qsplitlines to set to a basic shape upon startup of my program.  I have been playing around with the 4 numbers in setgerometry(x, x, x, x)  Could I get a simple explanation of what they correlate too?

## From top, ?, From left, ?

## (down starting from top, from left, continuing, how many rows it spas across)

```
hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

topleft = QtGui.QFrame(self)
topleft.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
topleft.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 0)

topright = QtGui.QFrame(self)
topright.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
topright.setGeometry(0, 320, 1000, 0)

bottom = QtGui.QFrame(self)
bottom.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
bottom.setGeometry(1210, 0, 1280, 0)

splitter1 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
splitter1.addWidget(topright)

splitter2 = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)
splitter2.addWidget(bottom)

hbox.addWidget(splitter2)

self.setLayout(hbox)
#QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm going to show you how to walk through the documentation before the answer at the bottom. It'll help you in the long run.

Start with the [`QFrame`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qframe.html) documentation. You are looking for a `setGeometry` method. You'll notice that there isn't one, but the QFrame does inherit from the `QWidget`

Going to the [`QWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html) documentation you'll find that there is are two [`setGeometry`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setGeometry) methods

```
QWidget.setGeometry (self, QRect)
```

and

```
QWidget.setGeometry (self, int ax, int ay, int aw, int ah)
```

The first one takes a `QRect` and the second takes series of integers. Let's look at the [`QRect`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qrect.html) docs too:

> A QRect can be constructed with a set of left, top, width and height integers

This lines up with the series of integers the other method takes. This image from the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry) helps explain it:

[image: Window Geometry]

Thus, your integers are:

- X coordinate
- Y coordinate
- Width of the frame
- Height of the frame